# sublime text webgl autocomplete

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, sublimetext2, webgl, sublimetext

I want to get into WebGL, but the functionnames feel so strange. Is there any way of getting the WebGL functions into sublime text's autocomplete?
If not, is there any way to get them into any other editor's autocomplete?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sublimetexts [package manager](https://packagecontrol.io/) gives you access the [WebGL Completions Package](https://github.com/katsew/webglcompletions).